# Pickle and Unpickle dict w/list as value

Tags: python, file, pickle

I have a dictionary with a list as a value such as:

```
numlist = {'Person': ['2342342', '15:05']}
```

I pickle it.

```
outfile = open{"log.txt", "wb")
pickle.dump(numlist, outfile)
```

I unpickle it.

```
infile = open("log.txt", "rb")
pickle.load(infile)
```

How do I convert this binary data back to it's original format? (a dictionary with the variable 'name' as the key, and the list with two items(a variable 'number' for the number and 'calltime' for the time) as the value)?

Comment: Please add these two lines: `x= pickle.load(infile)` and `print x`.  Then include the output as part of your question.

Comment: Er, by unpickling it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's try it:

```
In [22]: import pickle

In [23]: numlist = {'Person': ['2342342', '15:05']}

In [24]: outfile = open("log.txt", "wb")

In [25]: pickle.dump(numlist, outfile)

In [26]: outfile.close()

In [27]: infile = open("log.txt", "rb")

In [28]: pickle.load(infile)
Out[28]: {'Person': ['2342342', '15:05']}
```

As you can see, I got back exactly what I've started with (`numlist`). The only thing that's changed compared to your code is that I close `outfile` before re-opening it, to make sure that the buffers get flushed.

Comment: How do I get the contents of that into variables?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You started with a dictionary (`numlist`), you got back a dictionary. Just store it in a variable: `numlist_out = pickle.load(infile)`. And, BTW, you can't unpickle the same thing twice and expect it to work; you have to close and reopen the file.

Comment: I did a bit of debugging and figured it out.  Thanks again!